# Save Attachments of an email with specific subject from Outlook

Tags: vbscript

I have to read emails with specific subjects and save their attachments in a local folder.

Example I will get new email with subject "Subject 1", its attachment has to saved in "C:\Inputs\Subject 1" folder. Likewise if subject is "Subject 2" attachment is to be saved in "C:\Inputs\Subject 2" folder. After the attachment is saved, I need to move the mail to "Inputs" folder inside outlook. Not all the mails should be moved, only the ones with subject  "Subject 1" or "Subject 2".

The folders are already created, no need to create that. Just the filtering is done based on subject and attachments are to be saved based on the type of subject.

Comment: There are several requirement there, which one do you need help with? Can you show us what you've tried so far, and explain what isn't working?

Comment: We are doing a Robotic Process Automation where we need this entire scenario in vb script. I am not trained in vb scripting so looking for help.